# Centering multiple images in a <tr> element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm building this app which is an implementation of the game "Mancala". In a position of the board there can be "seeds" (game's piece) which I chose to represent as images.

In the initial setup of the game, there are N seeds in each position of the board. I represent this as N equal images ("seed.png") printed randomly in the respective position.

I want images to overlap, so even when N is a big number, they will all fit in the position ("see image nrº1"). What I accomplished so far is a random distribution with little to none overlapping and some "seeds" are getting out of the circle.

This is the code I have, built in JavaScript:

```
function init_board() {
    const board = document.getElementById("board");
    
    for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const tr = board.insertRow();
    if(i == 0) {
        tr.insertCell().setAttribute("rowSpan", "2");
    }

    for(let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        var x = tr.insertCell();
        for(let k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "images/seed.png";
        img.height = "10";
        img.width = "10";
        img.style.position = "relative";
        
        img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + "px";
        img.style.top = -7 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + "px";
        
        x.appendChild(img);
        }
    }
    
    if(i == 0) {
        tr.insertCell().setAttribute("rowSpan", "2");
    }
}
```

With the following formatting:

```
#board {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
}

td {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    border: 3px solid darkred;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: antiquewhite;
}

table {
    border: 5px solid darkred;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: burlywood;
}
```

Image Nrº1 N=20: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V17Nv.jpg,
Image Nrº2 where N=30 and the seeds change the size of the circle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ6AI.jpg

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide an editable, running sample of ypur code? You can use https://codepen.io/

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint.
https://codepen.io/guilherme-duarte-201905583/pen/bGrvMQy
I can't load the image I use, but it hitboxes are there so you can see where it should be.

Comment: Instead of CodePen, which many people can't use due to restrictions at work, how about [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), which are run here on Stack Overflow and don't require people to leave Stack Overflow to make sense of the question, or the answer, @MoaazBhnas?

Comment: Thank you. I will save this link and recommend Stack Snippets next times, @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply width and height correctly to `td` tag, you need to make it an `inline-block` element.

```css
td:not([rowspan="2"]) {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Your pen updated (with seeds=30): [CodePen](https://codepen.io/moaaz_bs/pen/oNeqdKq)

Comment: Even though with 30 seeds it didnt't expand the circle and seem to work, at 50 we can the seeds go off the position. Would you ming helping me with an solution for that?

Comment: ah, so you need to expand the circle as number of seeds grow?

Comment: No, sorry if I'm not explaining myself properly.
As the number of seeds increase, more overlaps should happen (because free space would decrease as well).

Comment: They go way off because `position: relative` actually moves them relative to _their_ current position, which overflows the circle. Check this example: https://codepen.io/moaaz_bs/pen/oNeqdKq

Comment: You need instead to position the seed relative to the circle, so you always gaurantee they spread within the circle. By giving the circle `position: relative`, and the seeds `position: absolute`. Will work on the pen.

Comment: Positioned the seeds randomly from 0 to 100% relative to the circles: https://codepen.io/moaaz_bs/pen/oNeqdKq?editors=0110